# JSF error message in wrong language

Tags: validation, jsf-2, message

I have JSF baed app which supports 4 different languages: english, german, french and italian.

The default locale in faces-config.xml is en

Every label or custom message is displayed correctly in the selected language in the application, except when english is selected for JSF default error messages(example for a mandatory field in a form). These messages are displayed in German.

"Gültigkeitsfehler: Es ist ein Wert erforderlich." instead of 
"Validation Error: Value is required."

For all the other languages, the messages are displayed correctly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you running a 'german' jdk? Or is the default OS language german?

Comment: The OS is in german, yes

Comment: Then it totally depends on how you implemented things in detail on why one works and the other not. Too much variables to even try to answer. I'd start by checking if the default language from the locales is actually used everywhere or that the server or even client language is used as a real default and you by accident use 'en' in other places

Answer (score 0):

I changed the websphere server language to english and now it works well